# Возможно ли сделать топологическую сортировку регулярных выражений?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, поиск

Я делаю небольшой поисковый движок, использующий регулярные выражения. Мне нужно сделать [топологическую сортировку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) регулярных выражений.
Небольшой пример, что я хочу получить.

Предположим, что я делаю поиск по подстрокам `"abc"`, `"bc"`, `"bcd"` and `"abcd"`.

`"bc"` это наиболее общая подстрока, результат поиска по `"bc"` вернет все результаты поиска, что и поиск по `"abc"`, `"bcd"` и `"abcd"`.

Строки `"abc"` и `"bcd"` более общие, чем `"abcd"`.

Но строки `"abc"` и `"bcd"` не сравнимы. Поиск по этим строкам вернет подмножества, которые могут не совпадать и не быть вложенными друг в друга.

Этот же пример в регулярных выражениях:

```
var bcRegex = /bc/;
var abcRegex = /abc/;
var bcdRegex = /bcd/;
var abcdRegex = /abcd/;

function regexComparator(regex1, regex2){...}

regexComparator(bcRegex, abcRegex); // => больше
regexComparator(abcRegex, bcRegex); // => меньше
regexComparator(bcRegex, bcRegex); // => равны
regexComparator(abcRegex, bcdRegex); // => не сравнимы
```

Возможно ли сделать функцию `regexComparator` для топологической сортировки регулярных выражений в общем случае для любых регулярных выражений?

Comment: Теоретически возможно, но очень сложно. Вам придется разбивать регулярные выражения на деревья токенов и сравнивать эти деревья на вхождение друг в друга, учитывая всякие edge cases типа "`[a-z][a-z0-9]+` входит в `\w*`"

Comment: Добавлю: топологическая сортировка обычно делается не компаратором...

Comment: Может подойти к задаче с другого конца? какова цель подобных манипуляций?

Comment: С той поры задача самоустранилась по нескольким причинам. Во-первых, это было весело и интересно дать конечному пользователю фильтрацию по регуляркам, но осознав, что даже не все программисты рады регуляркам, от этого отказались. Во-вторых, топологическая сортировка множеств полученных фильтрацией имела очень низкое соотношение полезности к затратам и от решения задачи отказались. Но задача осталась в истории.

Comment: Замечательная задача! Как узнать что язык одного автомата содержит в себе язык другого автомата?

Comment: Даже проверка равенства двух регулярных выражений сложна: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Deciding_equivalence_of_regular_expressions

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автор в комментариях явно указывает о том, что вопрос не актуален

Comment: @hedgehogues, неважно, актуален ли вопрос для автора.